# PySpark custom TimestampType column conversion

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to convert a String column, which is essentially a date, into a `TimestampType` column, however I'm having problems with how to split the value.

```
-RECORD 0-------------------------------------
 year                        | 2016           
 month                       | 4                         
 arrival_date                | 2016-04-30         
 date_added                  | 20160430           
 allowed_date                | 10292016
```

I have 3 columns, all of which are in different formats so I'm trying to find a way to split the string in a custom way, since the `date_added` column is yyyymmdd and the `allowed_date` is mmddyyyy.

I've tried something in the lines of:

```
df_imigration.withColumn('cc'.F.date_format(df_imigration.allowed_date.cast(dataType=t.TimestampType()), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

But with no success and I'm kind of stuck tring to find what's the right or best way to solve this.

The `t` and `F` aliases are for the following imports:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as t
```

Comment: use `F.to_timestamp` like this `df_imigration.withColumn('cc', F.to_timestamp("allowed_date","MMddyyyy"))`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you are casting the date without specifying the date format.
To specify the format you should use function to_timestamp().
Here I have created a dataframe with three different formats and it worked.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("20201231","12312020","31122020"), ("20201231","12312020","31122020" )], ["ID","Start_date","End_date"])

df1=df1.withColumn('cc',f.date_format(f.to_timestamp(df1.ID,'yyyymmdd'), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
df1=df1.withColumn('dd',f.date_format(f.to_timestamp(df1.Start_date,'mmddyyyy'), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
df1.withColumn('ee',f.date_format(f.to_timestamp(df1.End_date,'ddmmyyyy'), "yyyy-mm-dd")).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+----------+--------+----------+----------+----------+
|      ID|Start_date|End_date|        cc|        dd|        ee|
+--------+----------+--------+----------+----------+----------+
|20201231|  12312020|31122020|2020-12-31|2020-12-31|2020-12-31|
|20201231|  12312020|31122020|2020-12-31|2020-12-31|2020-12-31|
+--------+----------+--------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Hope it helps!